# short key or default setting for Pycharm debug button ("show python prompt")

Tags: debugging, user-interface, pycharm

I click the "show python prompt" button hundreds of times a day. Is there a way to set it to clicked by default or is there a short key to do this?

Edit --

I was told I can do this by going to:
Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Always show debug console

However I cannot find such a screen. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: The screen Piotr is showing is in the `Settings` window, Which you open either by clicking on the `File` menu at the top as he explains, or use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl Alt S` on windows/linux, or `Cmd ,` on mac

Answer (score 36):

You can turn on automatic showing of debug console by enabling *File|Settings|Build, Execution, Deployment|Console|Always show debug console* setting.

[image]

Comment: In addition, you can select in the Console tab: `Focus On Startup` and `Focus On Breakpoint`, in order to automatically show the debug console and enter **ipython**

Comment: The other reason this isn't an answer is because OP was asking about the "Show Python Prompt" setting specifically, not the debug console as a whole.

Comment: Not Mac OS, but using Win10, Pycharm Community 2020.1.2. I had the opposite of this problem, when launching debugger the "Show Python Prompt" would always be enabled (which is what OP wanted)  This prevented me from entering keyboard input from `raw_input` or `input` function calls.  Disabling this checkbox stopped this feature/option from being enabled by default. Also enabling this option re-enables the "Show Python Prompt" upon launching the debugger.
The order on windows is a little different in Windows10, but the text is the same "Always show debug console".  Thanks @piotr